# create a GenerationConfig for Google Gemini - 'Builder()' has private access

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I would like to create a new GenerationConfig for Google Gemini, having this in my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   
    GenerationConfig.Builder configBuilder = new GenerationConfig.Builder();
    configBuilder.temperature = 0.9f;
    configBuilder.topK = 16;
    configBuilder.topP = 0.1f;
    configBuilder.maxOutputTokens = 200;
    configBuilder.stopSequences = Arrays.asList("red");

    'Builder()' has private access in 'com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerationConfig.Builder'

    GenerationConfig generationConfig = configBuilder.build();

    GenerativeModel gm = new GenerativeModel(
            "MODEL_NAME",
            BuildConfig.apiKey,
            generationConfig
    );

    GenerativeModelFutures model = GenerativeModelFutures.from(gm);
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
 'Builder()' has private access in 'com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerationConfig.Builder'
```

my maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-vertexai</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please post a fill example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying following the example provided in this page in the [Android Google Documentation](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/android_quickstart?hl=es-419#model-parameters).

According to that documentation, you need to configure [the following dependencies](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/android_quickstart?hl=es-419#java_9) in your project, assuming you are using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other androidx dependencies

    // add the dependency for the Google AI client SDK for Android
    implementation("com.google.ai.client.generativeai:generativeai:0.1.1")

    // Required for one-shot operations (to use `ListenableFuture` from Reactive Streams)
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-android")

    // Required for streaming operations (to use `Publisher` from Guava Android)
    implementation("org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.4")
}
```

Please, note that the dependency `com.google.ai.client.generativeai:generativeai:0.1.1` is hosted in the [Google Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/), not in Maven Central.

If you want to keep using Maven you can try using the [following dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.ai.client.generativeai/generativeai/0.1.1):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.ai.client.generativeai</groupId>
    <artifactId>generativeai</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of the one you provided:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-vertexai</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As indicated, you probably will need to include a reference to the Google Maven Repository in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>google</id>
        <url>https://maven.google.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

In any case, you can achieve similar results using the Vertex AI you already configured in your `pom.xml` using a code similar to the following one (based in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/configure-safety-attributes?hl=es-419)):

```java
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.VertexAI;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerateContentResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerationConfig;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.preview.GenerativeModel;

public class GeminiAIExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Provide the required information about your Vertex AI GCP project
    String projectId = "your-google-cloud-project-id";
    String location = "us-central1";
    String modelName = "gemini-pro-vision";
    String textPrompt = "your-text-here";

    try (VertexAI vertexAI = new VertexAI(projectId, location)) {
      GenerationConfig generationConfig =
          GenerationConfig.newBuilder()
              .setTemperature(0.9F)
              .setTopK(16)
              .setTopP(0.1f)
              .setMaxOutputTokens(200)
              .setStopSequences(0, "red")
              .build();

      GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel(modelName, generationConfig, vertexAI);

      GenerateContentResponse response = model.generateContent(textPrompt);
      
      // Please, include the safety checks about the number of candidates, etc, you consider appropriate
      System.out.println(response.getCandidates(0).getContent());
    }
  }
}
```

Please, consider review [this](https://glaforge.dev/posts/2023/12/13/get-started-with-gemini-in-java/) or [this other](https://glaforge.dev/posts/2023/12/22/gemini-function-calling/) blog entries, I think they could be of help as well.